# Why does Learn Python The Hard Way suggest to "Read your .py file backwards."?

Tags: python

I am reading [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/wiki?name=Learn+Python+The+Hard+Way) and I am really curious what he means by

> Read your .py file backwards

Comment: Seems to fit better at programmers.stackexhange.com, IMO. It's fuzzy question.

Comment: Don't know, but it is at least info for next time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading something backwards word-for-word is also a great proofreading technique.

Often, when reading something forwards, you'll skip past words as you'll be assuming what comes next. Reading something backwards allows you to spot spelling errors more effectively.

Answer (score 14):

Exercise 41 (page 117) explains it better. This snippet:

```
cities['_find']=find_city
city_found=cities['_find'](cities,state)
```

reads like this when read backwards:

> 1. `state` and `city` are...
> 2. passed as parameters to...
> 3. a function at...
> 4. `_find` inside...
> 5. the dict `cities`...
> 6. and ﬁnally assigned to `city_found`.